# how to add png file to matlab plot

Tags: image, matlab, png

how do i add an image to a plot i made in matlab? the image is from wikipedia:

[image]

And below is the code i came up with for the plot i made.

```
x= 7:0.1:27;
y= normpdf(x,17,exp(1));
title('Normal Distribution')
hold on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
plot(x,y)
```

I think the script i need to use should be something like this but it's not working. Any ideas? thanks

```
title('addition: $1+1=2$', 'interpreter', 'latex')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the image itself to show up in your axes?  Or are you trying to have the equation in the image show up in your axes as text?  Because to do the first one you'd need:

```
x= 7:0.1:27;
y= normpdf(x,17,exp(1));
title('Normal Distribution')
hold on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
plot(x,y)

img = imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/3/a/73ad15f79b11af99bd2477ff3ffc5a35.png');
img = cat(3, img, img, img);
img = max(img(:)) - img;
img(img == max(img(:))) = 255;
hold on
xRange = [21 29];
yRange = [0.13 0.1];
imgHandle = image(linspace(xRange(1), xRange(2), size(img, 1)), ...
    linspace(yRange(1), yRange(2), size(img, 2)), img, 'Parent', gca);
hold off
```

which reads in the image from the URL given, tweaks it so it shows up as black text on white and then adds it to the axis as an object.

If instead you just want the text of the equation, which is what I think you're after as it is much more elegant, you'd do it this way:

```
x= 7:0.1:27;
y= normpdf(x,17,exp(1));
title('Normal Distribution')
hold on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
plot(x,y)

text(19, .145, '$f(x, \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$', ...
    'interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 14)
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I was trying to do it the second way. thank you for your help - it looks great!

Comment: one more question if you don't mind, i'm trying to add the standard deviation to the graph,  it looks like I should be using:                                         s = std(X)
s = std(X,flag)
s = std(X,flag,dim)                                                                                        but i can't get any of them to work correctly. is s=std(exp(1)) the correct syntax? thanks.

Comment: That's the correct syntax if you want `s` to be a single value equal to 0.  It would be easier to see where you went wrong if you provided the code to what you have done.

Comment: As u can see I am forcing lines for mean and standard deviation, it seems like I should be able to generate them more elegantly.                               x= 7:0.1:27;
y= normpdf(x,17,exp(1));
title('Normal Distribution')
hold on
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
plot(x,y)

text(19, .145, '$f(x, \mu, \sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$', ...
    'interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 14)

x=[17,17];
y=[0,.1465];
plot(x,y)

x=[14.22,14.22];
y=[0,.087];
plot(x,y)

x=[19.78,19.78];
y=[0,.087];
plot(x,y)